# Is there a way to append all lines to pattern space with sed?

Tags: linux, sed

```
seq 5 | sed -En 'N;N;N;N;s/(.|\n)+/a/p'
```

I can use `'a'` to replace the whole content. But I must use 4 `N` command to do that.

Is there a easy way? (What I want is handling all lines as one line)

`sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

EDIT: sample

`seq 5` will show 5 lines below,

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and I want to use sed's `s` command to parse the 5 lines as one line just like below:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed -En 'N;N;N;N;s|regex|something|p'
```

But I won't want use so much `N` command, so I need a smart way to append all lines to pattern space.

Comment: exactly how your lines will be show could you please tell

Comment: Why bother with the input if all you want is `a` in the output?  `seq 5 | echo a` does the job admirably.  You need to motivate the question more.

Comment: It's my negligence. What I want is handling all lines as one line.

Comment: I have to agree with @JonathanLeffler here. But you might consider `seq 5 | paste -s | sed whatever`, or `seq 5 | xargs | sed whatever`.

Comment: Could you post sample of desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/./a/g' file
```

or

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/./a/g' file
```

Both achieve the same result, the first using the normal program flow and the hold space, the second using the pattern space only but an internal loop.

N.B. this will replace all characters (including newlines) by `a` if this is not wanted replace only newlines `s/\n/a/g`, remove the newlines `s/\n//g;s/./a/g` or replace non-newlines `s/[^\n]/a/g`.

Comment: Thx! Your second solution is what I want.

Comment: If you were me, how would you describe my question? I think my description is not clear.

Comment: @BigShield I understand what you want but perhaps something like `Howto slurp a file into seds pattern space` or `howto slurp a file into memory using sed`?

Comment: Thx for your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

Superficially, what you're after might be:

```
:a
$! N
$ b c
b a
:c
s/\n+/a/gp
```

Save that in a file `script.sed`.  Then you can run:

```
$ seq 10 | sed -En -f script.sed
1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a10
$
```

The script creates a label, `a`.  For every line except the last (`$!`) it applies `N`.  For the last line, it jumps to label `c`.  Otherwise, it jumps back to label `a`.  The action at label `c` is to replace each newline with the letter `a`, and print the result.

While you can write all the script in arguments, the BSD (macOS) version of `sed` would require the two labels in their own `-e` arguments, so you'd end up with a lot of `-e` arguments (a minimum of four; you might as well have each line in its own `-e` argument).  `sed` won't care; people needing to maintain the code might.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do slurp whole input like this:

```
seq 5 | sed -n 'H;${g;s/regex/something/p}'
```

As for me it's easy to reproduce ;)